# Why does the route from private subnet only work with 0.0.0.0 route

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

My architecture:

```
EC2 in private subnet (10.0.0.0/24) --> NAT gateway in public subnet (10.0.0.8/24)
```

When i use the following routes in the private subnet, the connection from EC2 to the internet does not work.

```
10.0.0.0/24 nat-08a0fd199f0599e7c   Active  No
10.0.0.0/16 local   Active  No
```

If i change the the route table in the private subnet to this, it works:

```
0.0.0.0/0   nat-08a0fd199f0599e7c   Active  No
10.0.0.0/16 local   Active  No
```

But why is this? Both seem equivalent to me. My private subnet us really 10.0.0.0/24 and the ip i am testing it from is 10.0.0.62

and the reachibility analyzer says:

```
rtb-0470933497a2054a2 (demo-private-routetable)
NO_ROUTE_TO_DESTINATION:
Route table rtb-0470933497a2054a2 does not have an applicable route to igw-01f02d81bd80fc493. See rtb-0470933497a2054a2.
```

Comment: The IP you test *from* is irrelevant. The question is what IP you want to reach, where you want to go *to*. And without the 0.0.0.0 route most IPs will simply not be routable / reachable. You want to e.g. reach the IP 11.12.13.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is not right **10.0.0.0/24 nat-08a0fd199f0599e7c**. You need to route all traffic but the local one (10.0.0.0/16 in this case) through the NAT GW and for that you need to use the **0.0.0.0/0** CIDR range, that basically captures "all" traffic. For the local traffic the **10.0.0.0/16** is used as it has a longer prefix, therefore has a greater routing preference.

So, this is the correct configuration:

```
0.0.0.0/0   nat-08a0fd199f0599e7c   #Traffic outside the VPC (Internet)
10.0.0.0/16 local   #Internal VPC traffic (handled by the VPC router)
```